# Compare two items and copy missing children using Powershell

Tags: powershell

**Environment:** Sitecore 9.2 & SXA 1.9

**Scenario:** I have two different items and I would like to compare them and copy the missing children from one item to another using Powershell script.

- Item A (`DifferenceObject`) - If empty copy all the children from Item
  B and if few children are missing then copy them from Item B without
  disturbing the other children of Item A.
- Item B (`ReferenceObject`) - This item can have grandchildren as well.

This is the script that I am using but while running this script on the same item twice, it is making duplicate copies of children instead of ignoring them.

```
$itemA = Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/home/itemA"
$itemB = Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/home/itemB"

$diffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $itemB -DifferenceObject $itemA | 
Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

$diffs | Copy-Item -Destination $itemA.ID -Recurse
```

How to achieve this functionality? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: @MarekMusielak Yes, I used `Compare-Object` function, while I running the script twice on for the same item it is making duplicate copies instead of ignoring them.

Comment: @MarekMusielak Please check the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to copy child items from one folder to another using this simple script:

```
$targetPath = "/sitecore/content/home/test2/"

$itemAChildren = Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/content/home/test1" -recurse
$itemBChildren = Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/content/home/test2" -recurse

foreach ($itemAChild in $itemAChildren) {
    $exists = 0
    $createpath = $targetPath

        foreach ($itemBChild in $itemBChildren) {
            if ($itemAChild.Name -eq $itemBChild.Name) {
                $exists = 1
            }
        }
        
        if ($itemAChild.Parent.Paths.Path -eq "/sitecore/content/Home/Test1") {
            $createpath = $targetPath
        }
        else
        {
            $createpath = $itemAChild.Paths.Path
            $createpath = $createpath -replace "/sitecore/content/Home/Test1", "/sitecore/content/home/test2"
        }  
            
        if($exists -eq 0) {
            Copy-Item -Path $itemAChild.ItemPath -Destination $createpath
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Cristi, this script would be fine when an item has children but in the case of grandchildren it will not perform as desired. I tried to `-Recurse` both items, it is copying the grandchildren under the item directly instead of the item's children.

Comment: So you are trying to copy the whole structure of children from all levels?

Comment: Yes, that's why I was trying to use `Compare-Object`. Do you have any suggestions on how to implement this functionality without writing multiple `foreach` for child/grandchild contains children?

Comment: I updated the answer, what would remain would be the check of the existence as there can be multiple items with the same name. I think there it must be added a line to check also the name of the parent